# Change variable value using onchange

Tags: javascript

I want to change the value of `value` using a `change` event listener. Is it possible? Here is my sample code:

```
<select name="select1" onchange="updatevariable(this.value)"> 
    <option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="15" >15</option> 
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    value = "test";
    function updatevariable(data) { 
        value = data;       
    }
    alert(value); // It should be 2/15
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: The `alert` is executed *before* you make any change to the select field (at the time when you assign `value = "test";` and define `updatevariable`, not when you *call* `updatevariable`). Put it *inside* the event handler.

Comment: what is the issue. it seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/JmpSU/

Comment: @Pekka When I run this code. Its display alert `hello`. Not `2/15`

Comment: @mridkash it is not working on that fiddle, read question again

Comment: Are you sure it prints `hello`? Should be `test`.

Comment: @FelixKling Can i use value variable outside function ?

Comment: @MarekSebera OP wants to change the `value` variable `onchange`. That is working perfectly fine! Not being able to see it working using alert is another thing.

Comment: @mridkash OP wants to change the value variable, and then alert it's value. Alert it not giving what OP expects (as you can see from his comment on that line) so this is what he needs to fix.

Comment: I think you'd profit from reading the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `alert()` in wrong place

```
<select name="select1" onchange="updatevariable(this.value)"> 
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="15" >15</option> 
 </select>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var value = "test";
    function updatevariable(data) { 
        value = data;
        alert(value);
    } 
 </script>
```

In your code it is loaded right after the script is loaded,
you have to modify it to be called right after change

Comment: Can I use `value ` variable outside the function?

Comment: yes, but the value is changed only after calling `updatevariable` function

Comment: Thats What i want. Can you please give any example?

Comment: cannot give you an example. simply use variable `value` whetever you need. you can use it within functions as well as in inline script. Just note that `variable is usable after its declaration`, so you cannot use it before you create it.