# How to establish relationship between option tag of different select tags in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have three select tags in HTML with option tag.I want to establish relationship between option tags of different select tag.

**EDIT-1**

When I choose Reference-1 from select name="reference" then 2014-10-10 07:17:00 and 2014-10-10 08:46:00 from select name="from" and select name="to" should only be present in the dropdown list.When I choose Reference-2 then 2014-09-01 10:00:00 and 2014-09-01 11:00:00 should only be present in dropdown list of **from** and **to** select tag. My html code for is-

```html
<form method="post">
Select Reference:
<select name="reference">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<option value="Reference-1">Reference-1;</option>
<option value="Reference-2">Reference-2</option>
<option value="Reference-3">Reference-3</option>
<option value="Reference-4">Reference-4</option>
</select>
 From Date:
<select name="from">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<option value="2014-10-10 07:17:00">2014-10-10 07:17:00</option>
<option value="2014-09-01 10:00:00">2014-09-01 10:00:00</option>
<option value="2014-09-08 10:00:00">2014-09-08 10:00:00</option>
</select>
 To Date:
<select name="to">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<option value="2014-10-10 08:46:00">2014-10-10 08:46:00</option>
<option value="2014-09-01 11:00:00">2014-09-01 11:00:00</option>
<option value="2014-09-08 10:00:00">2014-09-08 11:00:00</option>
</select><br>

<b>Select Date to be compared</b>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: can be more specific , explain a bit more what you need

Comment: Explain clearly and be more specific. We cannot get anything from your question

Comment: I believe that you need to use javascript for that ...

Comment: @Radek,I also think so,but how??

Comment: Onchange of the "master" select will update options of the other select(s). I do not know if only html can be used here....maybe... this javascript way is guaranteed ... something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538136/change-variable-value-using-onchange

Comment: @Radek I tried the above mentioned link java script ,but its of no use .A message box is displayed which shows the selected Reference.

Comment: @MES what if you select `Reference-3` or `Reference-4` from `reference` select element?

Comment: @AshadShanto then the corresponding 3 and 4 option value from respective select name should be selected.Here its one to one relation i.e for first (Reference-1)select option all the first select option values from respective from and to select name should be selected .

Comment: do you prefer `jQuery` or vanilla javascript solution?

Comment: @AshadShanto javascript solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index of the selected option from `reference` select element and then disable all the options of `from` and `to` select elements except the option with index of the previous index you got from `reference` select option.

***javaScript Solution :***

```
var reference = document.getElementsByName("reference")[0];

var fromSelect = document.getElementsByName("from")[0];
var toSelect = document.getElementsByName("to")[0];

reference.onchange = function(){
    var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    for(var i = 1; i <= fromSelect.length; i++){
        if(i != selectedIndex){
            fromSelect.getElementsByTagName("option")[i].disabled = true;
            toSelect.getElementsByTagName("option")[i].disabled = true;
        } else{
            fromSelect.getElementsByTagName("option")[i].disabled = false;
            toSelect.getElementsByTagName("option")[i].disabled = false;
        }
    }
};
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/sashb4m8/)

***jQuery Solution :***

```
$("select[name='reference']").on("change", function(){
    var $fromSelect = $("select[name='from']");
    var $toSelect = $("select[name='to']");
    var selectedIndex = $(this).children("option:selected").index();
    $fromSelect.children("option").removeAttr("disabled");
    $toSelect.children("option").removeAttr("disabled");
    $fromSelect.children("option").not(":eq(" + selectedIndex +")").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    $toSelect.children("option").not(":eq(" + selectedIndex +")").prop("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/5Lqo62z8/)

Answer (score 2):

If second selection values are dependent on the first selection option, then you should disable the whole second selection until the first one is selected.
When the first one is selected then disable all the unrelated options in second selection and make it enabled to the user. Let me know if it helped.

```
$("select[name='reference']").on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val(); // first selection value

    if ("Reference-1" == value ) {
      var $selection2 = $("select[name='from']");
      $selection2.find("option[value*='2014-09-01 10:00:00']").prop('disabled',true);
      $selection2.find("option[value*='2014-09-08 10:00:00']").prop('disabled',true);
    }
    ...
});
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xp5p5/16/)

Comment: ,how to enable and disable when particular option is selected?

Comment: Nice. I would also select the option. But I guess it was not in the original question.